# SQL Server Data Tool (SSDT) in Visual Studio 2012 not compatible with SQL Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I cannot create a new SQL Server Database Project on my machine that have installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and SQL Server 2012

[image]

I got the below error saying that the SQL Server runtime components not matched.

Do you have the same issue? And what is the work-around for this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download the latest version of SSDT from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027 (or by clicking the "Get the latest version" link in the error message). SSDT uses a shared component called DacFx, and when you installed SQL Server 2012 on your machine a newer version of DacFx was installed. Updating SSDT will ensure everything is compatible.

Note: Make sure you have a stable internet connection, otherwise you may have issues installing from the web installation and/or the .iso file download.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I'll update SSDT. Clicking `get latest version` link me to the visual studio home page which is not specificly related to SSDT.

Comment: I downloaded the iso image and install SSDT Oct 2013 from that and get the error with log file here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/sql_SSDT_1100_20131206163843.log. I don't know what is going on :(

Comment: It looks like the installer failed when trying to copy an MSI to the temp directory. All the other MSIs were cached inside "C:\Program Data", the the likely issue is either that the installer didn't have permissions to copy to that directory? I would try clearing your TEMP directory, restarting your computer and installing again.  

[0F40:1204][2013-12-06T16:39:51]: Error 0x80070001: Failed attempt to copy payload from: 'D:\ssdt\x86\SSDTBuildUtilities.msi' to: C:\Users\NamVG1\AppData\Local\Temp\{222691b1-c9a6-4361-bc8f-4baed1d9169f}\SSDTBUILDUTILITIES11.

Comment: Today a colleague give me his downloaded iso with different size and I got SSDT installed now. The cause was the incomplete .iso file.

Answer (score 0):

ISO file download is the problem. This is the second time I have seen the ISO image from MS website has this problem in 1 month. Some are corrupted there are no such files like ".be" prefix "." + file name. Bad file name caused everything.